# select2 tags with no names

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I'm using this bit of code to apply the tags of selections made on a previous page which were saved to the db.

It creates the tags but does not put the text in them just puts a X to remove it.
selected is an array of possible locations.

i.e `["work", "home", "away", "Hong Kong", "Manchester".......]`

```
var selected = this.location
var $element = $("#location").select2();
for (var d = 0; d < selected.length; d++) {
    var item = selected[d];
    var option = new Option(item.text, item.id, true, true)
    $element.append(option);
}
```

any help would be appreciated as all the select2 issues on here seem to be mainly dealing with static data or are to advanced for my current level of knowledge.

As requested,

Thats all there is to it code wise. I just want text in the tags

It currently looks like this http://prntscr.com/a1h2nu
I need it to look like this http://prntscr.com/a1h33w

Here is the HTML

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Location</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <select class="form-control" id="location" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">
            </select>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
    </div>



var item = selected[d];
console.log(item);
var option = new Option(item.text, item.id, true, true)
console.log(option);
$element.append(option);
```

this it the dev tools output
http://prntscr.com/a1hdf7

Comment: Can you provide more code or explain the situation better. The description above is too vague.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't programmatically select option using Select2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128770/cant-programmatically-select-option-using-select2)

Comment: well is is on a page load. the page should load with the tags populated

Comment: Hi SpeedyH30, it seems to me that the fact that is on page load should be irrelevant. If tags are not added, then you need to fire the change, if text is not added, just log if your item.text is populated... Possibly the problem is not on Select2 but in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a simple fix
From this...

```
var item = selected[d];
console.log(item);
var option = new Option(item.text, item.id, true, true)
console.log(option);
$element.append(option);
```

To this...

```
var item = selected[d];
console.log(item);
var option = new Option(item, item.id, true, true)
console.log(option);
$element.append(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
Updated jsFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gw7bpy0s/4/). Main problem is that you missed the correct selector.

In order for Select2 to take into account your changes you need to trigger the change so the control is reevaluated.

You can see a live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gw7bpy0s/1/)

As in

```
$(".js-programmatic-set-val").on("click", function () { $example.val("CA").trigger("change"); });
```

Reference to Select2 Documentation [Programmatic Access](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic)

Comment: no. select2 works fine when selecting something new. the tags need to be there when the page renders.

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle that does exactly that https://jsfiddle.net/gw7bpy0s/2/

Comment: in all honestly I have no idea, 
all of this `var $element = $("#location").select2();
    for (var d = 0; d < selected.length; d++) {
      var item = selected[d];
      console.log(item);
      var option = new Option(item.text, item.id, true, true)
      console.log(option);
      $element.append(option);`
is from the select2 page I just want my array of select to populate the tags. thats all

Comment: If you want your code to be debugged, SO shouldn't be the tool, but if you want to have a chance someone helps you with that, you really need to provide a full jsfiddle...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've given more information about my issue then most people who have problems do. I can't really create an entire jfiddle For my entire function

Comment: Check a good question vs yours and you have got your answer if your is good ( Hint: answer is no). For example, you don't give the definition of d.

Comment: that would be because I dont know what it is. AS I STATED THIS CODE IS SELECT2s CODE. hence the issue being a select2 issue not a js one. but If I had to guess lookin at the who code I gave you at the start in question d is just a var to increment id `(var d = 0; d < selected.length; d++)` so wind your neck in befor getting all high and mighty. typical JS coder attitude from you.

Comment: My fault on d, but the rest stays true. Anyway, the updated fiddle explained your problem but you preferred to insult me rather than thanking.

Comment: well you haven't really have you? all you have done is created a jfiddle with two types of static data in it. the reason mine isnt working isbecause the contents of `selected` i.e the locations are not populating the `item.text`  in new Option and I cant see why. That's the only issuer I have the rest of it works

Comment: The idea of giving a fiddle ( and by the way YOU should have done it in the first place ) is to collaborate on the resolution. JsFiddle is there https://jsfiddle.net/gw7bpy0s/6/, you don't think it reflects your code? Go on, change it, press on update and share it with the community. You don't want to, no problem, but please don't put on people trying to help you. It's unfair and rude.